# Delphi RegEx Parenthesis Parser

Tags: regex, pcre, subroutine, parentheses

I am looking for an regular expression as generally solution.

This regular expression is used to obtain parenthetical functions and parameters.

**Input:**

```
...alotOfText...
DBINFO("Parameter1"|'FirstFunction(Parameter)'|Parameter3|SecondFunction("Parameter1"|Parameter2)")
...alotOfOtherText...
```

Current regex:

```
  cRegex =
       'DBINFO\('// Looking for DBINFO(
     + '(?:' // Recursion for following Pattern(s)
     + '[^\)]' // no "("
     + '|(?R))' // or Repeat the Recursion (am i right?) I don't really understand this line
     + '*\)' // Quantifier for recursion (?) with unlimited Chars and one ")" at the end.
     ;
```

For inputs with only one set of `()` this works, but as soon as I need to parse the input mentioned above, the matches are only until the first occurrence of a `)`.

So I researched that multiple levels of parenthesis need to use sub routines. But even on my primary information source I can't find an example that brings me back on track. http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html

Remarks:

Each parameter could be blank, with " or with ' (mixed)

Source:

```
hRegEx := TRegEx.Create(cRegex), [roIgnoreCase, roMultiLine]);
hMatchCollection := hRegEx.Matches(aLayoutString);

  for hMatch in hMatchCollection do 
  // Regarding the Regular Expression there should only be one Match in the Collection. 
  //Thats Subject to Change
  begin
    if hMatch.Success then
    begin
      Result := ParseParameter(hMatch.Value);
    end;
  end;
```

If you give an example: Please comment on it as mine. I want to believe .. ah learn. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If I'm understanding you correctly, your question is about the regular expression itself, and has nothing to do with Delphi other than you choosing to add the block of Delphi code at the bottom. If your question is actually about Delphi, can you [edit] to make it more clear what *Delphi* problem you're looking for help solving?

Comment: Yes i am new. The Reg Ex which is used is the Delphi XE Version. (PCREG?) I added the source to show how i am currently using my Version 0.1. (Since an change of the Expression could change the whole matching Groups ...)

Comment: You should then [edit] to remove the Delphi tag, and replace it with the PCRE tag. Once you get a regular expression that's working, the Delphi code to use it would be pretty much the same (and if it doesn't work, you'd then have a *new, different question* about that problem).

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expressions? A simpler and better approach might be to tokenise the string, and for each `(` increment your level, and decrement when you hit a `)`.

Comment: Yes your right, i could. But I thought that way it would be easier for 3. Partys to build their own "Tokenizer" without recreating from my Documentation. If i cant find an Solution i will do it the Tokenizer way.

Answer (score 1):

Found!

```
cRegex =
     'DBINFO'              // some Searchinfo outside the parenthesis Expression
   + '('                   // Outer Match Start for (?1)
   +   '\('                // Search one "("
   +   '('                 // "SubGroup" Start 
   +     '(?>[^()]+)'      // SubPattern:  everything that is non-parentheses
   +     '|(?1)'           // or recursive match of the Subpattern 1
   +   ')'                 // "SubGroup" End
   +   '*\)'               // any Numer of "SubGroup" and one ")"
   + ')'                   // Outer Match End
   ;
```

I was wrong with my first Expression. The Paranthesis Expression itself was perfectly fine. So this seems to work fine.

Found at:
http://mushclient.com/pcre/pcrepattern.html#SEC19

If someone with more knowledge could correct my Comments about the Expression. First i am using the wrong Names. Second i am not sure if (?1) reffers to the Inner () or the Outer () Match. And i dont know how to format Expressions.